# Max heigh and max width doesn't work in image_cropper

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to set default and locked size of the crop borders but I can't find a way for doing it. There are only a few ratios is settings. Max heigh and max width doesn't work for me.

Is there a way I can do that in image cropper?

Here is my full code I have written. It would be amazing if someone had a solution for my problem, thanks in advance.

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final CameraDescription camera;

  const HomePage({
    Key key,
    @required this.camera,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  MyAppState createState() => MyAppState();
}

enum AppState {
  free,
  picked
}

class MyAppState extends State<HomePage> {
  CameraController _controller;
  Future<void> _initializeControllerFuture;
  AppState state;  

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    state = AppState.free;
    _controller = CameraController(
      widget.camera,
      ResolutionPreset.medium,
    );
    _initializeControllerFuture = _controller.initialize();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void takePic() async {
    try {
      await _initializeControllerFuture;
      final path = join(
        (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path,
        '${DateTime.now()}.png',
      );
      await _controller.takePicture(path);
      File image = await ImageCropper.cropImage(
      sourcePath: path,
      androidUiSettings: AndroidUiSettings(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          hideBottomControls: true,
          initAspectRatio: CropAspectRatioPreset.original,
          lockAspectRatio: true),
      aspectRatioPresets: [
        CropAspectRatioPreset.square,
      ],
      );
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => Picture(
            image: image,
          ),
        ),
      );
      GallerySaver.saveImage(image.path);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder<void>(
        future: _initializeControllerFuture,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            return Stack(children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                width: size.width,
                height: size.height * 0.8,
                child: CameraPreview(_controller),
              ),
              
              CameraButton(takePic),
            ]);
          } else {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Picture extends StatelessWidget {
  final File image;

  const Picture({Key key, this.image}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Image.file(image),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you Share your code?

Comment: I udpated question